# Mapping User Input to Text File List

Tags: python, function, pseudocode

I'm trying to make a function that, given input from the User, can map input to a list of strings in a text file, and return some integer corresponding to the string in the file. Essentially, I check if what the user input is in the file and return the index of the matching string in the file. I have a working function, but it seems slow and error-prone.

```
def parseInput(input):
    Gates = []
    try: 
        textfile = open("words.txt")
        while nextLine:
             nextLine = textfile.readline()
             Gates[n] = nextLine #increment n somewhere
    finally:
        textfile.close()
    while n <= len(Gates):
        nextString = Gates[n]
        if input in nextString:
            #Exit loop
    with open("wordsToInts.txt") as textfile:
        #Same procedure as the try loop(why isn't that one a with loop?)
        if(correct):
            return number
```

This seems rather... bad. I just can't seem to think of a better way to do this though. I have full control over words.txt and wordsToInts.txt(should I combine these?), so I can format them as I please. I'm looking for suggestions re: the function itself, but if a change to the text files would help, I would like to know. My goal is to reduce cause for error, but I will add error checking later. Please, suggest a better way to write this function. If writing in code, please use Python. Pseudocode is fine, however.

Answer (score 0):

I would say to combine the files. You can have your words, and their corresponding values as follows:

**words.txt**

```
string1|something here
string2|something here
```

Then you can store each line as an entry to a dictionary and recall the value based on your input:

```
def parse_input(input):
    word_dict = {}
    with open('words.txt') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            line_key, line_value = line.split('|', 1)
            word_dict[line_key] = line_value.rstrip('\n')
    try:
        return word_dict[input]
    except KeyError:
        return None
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to make a function that, given input from the User, can map input to a list of strings in a text file, and return some integer corresponding to the string in the file. Essentially, I check if what the user input is in the file and return the index of the matching string in the file

```
def get_line_number(input):
    """Finds the number of the first line in which `input` occurs.

    If input isn't found, returns -1.
    """
    with open('words.txt') as f:
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
            if input in line:
                return i
    return -1
```

This function will meet the specification from your description with the additional assumption that the string you care about are on separate lines. Notable things:

1. File objects in Python act as iterators over the lines of their contents. You don't have to read the lines into a list if all you need to do is check each individual line.
2. The `enumerate` function takes an iterator and returns a generator which yields a tuple like `(index, element)`, where `element` is an element in your iterator and index is its position inside the iterator.

   - The term iterator means any object that's a sequence of things you can access in a for loop.
   - The term generator means an object which generates elements to iterate through "on-the-fly". What this means in this case is that you can access each line of a file one by one without having to load the entire file into your machine's memory.
3. This function is written in the standard Pythonic style, with a docstring, appropriate casing on variable names, and a descriptive name.